# how to get information from another controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to save information using another controller to store it in the database.
in my situation, there are two controllers:

- PostingsController
- CommentsController

I could make the create function for comment using CommentsController, but I could not save post_id in the database from CommentsController.
I would like to save post_id using PostingsController because it has:

```
//if user did not fill the form properly
    //error messages will popup
    $this->validate($request, [
        'comment' => 'required',
    ]);

    //if user filled the form properly
    //store the form
    $comment = new Comment();
    //for connecting both user and comment
    $comment->user_id = Auth::id();

    //to store comment
    $comment->post_id = //I want to save post_id from PostingsController
    //to store comment
    $comment->comment = $request->input('comment');
    //save all user input
    $comment->save();
    dd($comment);
```

I have set $comment = Posting::id();, but it could not work. the error is:

```
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\Models\Posting::id()
```

my PostingsController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Posting;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class PostingsController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //this is how to get all posting, but this shows only all posting
        // $postings = Posting::all();
        // $postings->load('user');
        //this is how to get all posting with created_at and descending order.
        $postings = Posting::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        //should be function name
        $postings->load('user');


        return view('index')->with('postings', $postings);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //if user did not fill the form properly
        //error messages will popup
        $this->validate($request, [
            'posting' => 'required',
        ]);

        //if user filled the form properly
        //store the form
        $posting = new Posting();
        //for connecting both user and posting
        $posting->user_id = Auth::id();
        //to store posting
        $posting->post = $request->input('posting');
        //save all user input
        $posting->save();

        return redirect()->to('/home')->with('success', 'Posting created successfully!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $posting = Posting::find($id);
        return view('show')->with('posting', $posting);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //this is the way how to find posting of authenticated user
        $posting = Posting::find($id);

        return view('edit')->with('posting', $posting);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //if user did not fill the form properly
        //error messages will popup
        $this->validate($request, [
            'posting' => 'required',
        ]);

        //if user filled the form properly
        //store the form
        $posting = Posting::find($id);
        //to store posting
        $posting->post = $request->input('posting');
        //save all user input
        $posting->save();

        return redirect()->to('/home')->with('success', 'Posting edited successfully!');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $posting = Posting::find($id);
        $posting->delete();

        return redirect()->to('/home')->with('success', 'Posting deleted successfully');
    }


}
```

my CommentsController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Posting;
use App\Models\Comment;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('comments.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //if user did not fill the form properly
        //error messages will popup
        $this->validate($request, [
            'comment' => 'required',
        ]);

        //if user filled the form properly
        //store the form
        $comment = new Comment();
        //for connecting both user and comment
        $comment->user_id = Auth::id();

        //to store comment
        $comment->post_id = //problem
        //to store comment
        $comment->comment = $request->input('comment');
        //save all user input
        $comment->save();
        dd($comment);

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

create.comments in view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="float-left m-2">Create new comment</div>
                    <span class=" "><a href="/home" class="float-right btn btn-primary">Go back</a></span>
                </div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <form method="post" action="/comments" >

                        @csrf
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="{{ $post->id }}" />
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Comment what you think!">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Comment</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Just store the post ID in a hidden field in the comment form...

Comment: it did not work..
I set this i
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="{{ $post->id }}" />

and error is Undefined variable: post

Comment: where is your form?

Comment: If it were me, I'd put the post_id in the comment resource routes.  Something like https://example.com/posts/123/comments/create 
see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: @albus_severus I updated

Answer (score 1):

Following the principle of [**Separation of Concerns**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) you can move the **logic** into another module such as **services**.

I would suggest adding a new folder `app/services` and adding a service-class for each logic that needs to be implemented, eg. `app/services/AddCommentToPostService.php`.

This will also make testing of the system easier.

Answer (score -1):

you can use app method to call controller method of another controller in laravel app('App\Http\Controllers\ControllerName')->functionName();

Comment: it did not work..
I want to set post_id using PostingsController. because PostingsController has post_id. CommentsController does not have post_id